# Apache CXF 3.4.2 JDK 11 - Issue while Wsdl2Java. Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelperImpl

Tags: java, maven, cxf

Am trying to generate Java code from wsdl using apache cxf 3.4.2 & JDK 11 .
Getting following exceptions

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelperImpl
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelperImpl can not implement org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper, because it is not an interface (org.apache.cxf.common.util.ASMHelper is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

following is snippet from pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
            <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.basedir}/src/main/generated</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/test.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/test.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>com.cxf</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you'll try to find `ASMHelper` class in your IDE then you can see that your class look like this: `public class ASMHelper` (`cxf-core:3.3.0` / `cxf-core:3.3.1` / `cxf-core:3.3.5`) so indeed it's not an interface. However when you look at `ASMHelper` in `cxf-core:3.4.4` you'll see `public interface ASMHelper` which can be implemented.

So problem is caused by old version of library.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was solved by aligning all the CXF type dependencies 3.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the `cxf-api` dependency from your pom.xml. It is outdated and has the class `ASMHelper.java` which is getting loaded instead of the interface of same name from `cxf-core` jar which is the right package to load. No need to declare `cxf-core` separately, it is transitively included as part of `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws`

Answer (score -1):

Change version of plugin from:

> 3.3.0

to

> 3.4.2